# How to find repeated cell vectors in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, cell-array

I have `n` different length cell vectors, call it `c{i}`, i=1,2,...,n.

I wanna find those c{i} which equal with others, for example:

```
c{1}=[1 2 3 4 5 6]; c{2}=[1 3 5 7]; c{3}=[2 4 6 8];
c{4}=[1 4 6]; c{5}=[3 7]; c{6}=[2 4 6 8]; c{7}=[1 3 5 7];
```

I hope I can find `[2 4 6 8]` and `[1 3 5 7]` with a simple way instead of using two loops.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/unique.html). You need to convert vectors to strings, because `unique` works with cell arrays of strings but not with cell arrays of numeric vectors. After `unique`, you can count how many strings (vector) are repeated with [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/histc.html), and them some indexing lets you retrieve the corresponding vectors:

```
strcell = cellfun(@(e) num2str(e), c, 'uniformoutput', 0); %// convert to strings
[~, ii, jj] = unique(strcell); %// apply unique. Second and third outputs needed
ind = find(histc(jj,min(jj)-.5:max(jj)+.2)>1); %// which appear more than once
result = c(ii(ind)); %// indexing to obtain corresponding original vectors
```